# Hard drive partitioning

Tags: partition

I have Linux installed on my computer. I have `/dev/sda1` where the mount point is `/` and `/dev/sda2` which contains `/dev/sda5` which is my swap space.

I want to partition /dev/sda1. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: `/dev/sda1` is already partitioned, and it contains `/`: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: /dev/sda1 contains all of the hard drive excluding swap. I am trying to partition that.

Comment: You really want to shrink /dev/sda1, grow /dev/sda2, and add partitions inside /dev/sda2... rather than splitting /dev/sda1.  You can do these operations through the GUI with gparted

Answer (score 1):

You'd need a Live flash or CD with your favorite Linux distro (cause you can't re-partition the partition, from which your system is currently running).

So, you boot with that flash/CD (in BIOS menu select it as the boot device) and run some partition utility from it, like GParted. GParted has graphical interface and is quite intuitive. There you just split your /dev/sda1 into several partitions.

Before re-partitioning your `/dev/sda1` you'd better back up your data on it - copy them to some other media. Current partitioning tools are pretty safe, but better not take risks.

You could also backup your master boot record MBR (first 512 bytes of your `/dev/sda`, contains information about partition locations and types and first stage of bootloaer) and optionally DOS compatibility region (spans from byte 513 to the end of 32nd KiB of your `/dev/sda`, may contain bootloader stage 2 or 1,5) with `dd`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/mbr-backup bs=512 count=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split `/dev/sda1` into 2 smaller partitions, the way to go ahead is to make a backup of the data on /dev/sda1, then boot from a CD or USB and create 3 new primary partitions: `sda1`, `sda2`, `sda3`. With `sda3` the size of your current swap and the others dividing the rest.

If this is a remote machine and you have no way to boot from CD/USB, don't need to make a backup (or if everything on `sda1` fits in the size of the swap partition, **and** if you have enough memory so you don't need swap-space (assuming you don't do anything excessive), you can do a repartition with the following steps:

1. deactivate swap
2. remove `sda2`
3. create an extend partition `sda4`
4. create a normal partition `sda5` in `sda4`
5. make a filesystem on `sda5`
6. copy all of the files from `sda1` to `sda5`
7. adjust /etc/fstab on the filesystem on `sda5`
8. run grub-install and make sure sda5 can be selected (often the UUID needs to be adjusted in /boot/grub/grub.cfg)
9. change GRUB_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub or and re-run and adjust UUID.
10. reboot

After the reboot you will now be running from `/dev/sda5`, you can then remove partition `sda1` and replace it with `sda1` and `sda2`. Once that is setup, you can repeat the process above to move things back from `sda5` to `sda1`. After a second reboot you are back with `/` on `sda1` and re-configure sda5 as swap space.

I did the above on a remote hosted server (running Ubuntu 8.04) succesfully to make a `/` and `swap` setup into a `/`, `/home` and `swap` setup. If you have never done such a thing before, I recommend trying it out on a virtual machine first, because if you make a mistake, you won't be able to regain access to the machine, unless you can get to the console prompt somehow.

Comment: Step 9 really doesn't make much sense.